# How to use NULL in a .cpp file?

Tags: c++, null-pointer

I'm studying the only instance now(in c++), and I tried the following code in my .cpp file.

```
#include "OnlyInstance.h"

OnlyInstance* OnlyInstance::instance = NULL;
..........
```

but the compiler told me "error C2065: 'NULL' : undeclared identifier".
So is that means, I should

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

in front of it? But I also included stdio.h in the main file. So stdio.h will be included many times when compiling, right? How can I use NULL correctly?

Another question is that, I know I can use 0 instead of NULL, but which way is more recommended in c++?

Comment: As an aside, as you are initializing a static pointer with `NULL`, you could also simply omit the initializer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`NULL`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) is defined in various headers, for example in `<cstddef>`.

You should however prefer `nullptr` over `NULL` if your compiler supports this.

Including a header multiple times is no problem (if the header is not horribly broken, which the standard headers are not).

Comment: which it should for C++11 and later.

Comment: But if I do #include <stdio.h> in OnlyInstance.cpp and main.cpp at the same time, then #include 'OnlyInstance.h' in main.cpp. What will the compiler do?  stdio.h will be included twice? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

NULL is only a define with a value of 0. It is exactly the same.

But if you have access to C++11, I would recommend using nullptr.

Comment: Actually, it can be something else. Which is one of the reasons to prefer `nullptr`.

Comment: Technically, it is a 0 of the same size as a pointer, so it may be 0 or 0L or 0LL depending on what integer type matches a pointer. Otherwise, things like `printf("%p", NULL);` will go wrong.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: That would be nice, sometimes, for hiding errors. It isn't guaranteed though.

Comment: Ok, it may not apply to ALL compilers, but it certainly worked better in my experience than the `printf("%p", 0);` that some test-code I had to deal with when I implemented printf - it took a while to identify the problem, as it was hidden a little better than the code in this comment...